# Constantly check screens width/height? (update a function)

Tags: html, cordova

I was wondering if there is any way to update a function in javascript for a html site I have.

My code if below and I just want to execute my function constantly. Almost like how the Unity3D game engine has a "void Update()" and what ever is put into it is constantly ran through.

I am using cordova to make my site an app and need to have a way to detect if the device is landscape or portrait.

Thanks!

```
 if(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight){all of my code....}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it for you, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/54/

The `onresize="myFunction()"` is what will trigger the event everytime the page is resized.

javascript

```
  function myFunction() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    if (width > height) {
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<h1>landscape</h1>';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<h1>portrait</h1>';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!